# Add column headings to the table & border the cells

Tags: python, python-3.x, openpyxl

I want to do the two things in the code below.

1. Adding column headings to the table
2. Border the cells

I guess, solution for the column headings can be solved with "using a for loop or range", but I couldn't manage how to do it.

And for the border lines, I don't have any opinion on how to do that.

Thank you.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QDialogButtonBox
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QFormLayout
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QLineEdit
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QVBoxLayout
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
import openpyxl
filename = "data.xlsx"
def checkfile():
    from os import path
    if not path.exists(filename):
        wb = openpyxl.Workbook()

        ws = wb.worksheets[0]

        ws.cell(2, 1).value = 'First Name'
        ws.cell(3, 1).value = 'Second Name'
        ws.cell(4, 1).value = 'Age'
        ws.cell(5, 1).value = 'Sex'
        ws.cell(6, 1).value = 'Marital Status'
        ws.cell(7, 1).value = 'Education'
        ws.cell(8, 1).value = 'Job'
        wb.save(filename)
class InputDialog(QDialog):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setWindowTitle("Information Window")
        self.first = QLineEdit()
        self.second = QLineEdit()
        self.third = QLineEdit()
        self.fourth = QLineEdit()
        self.fifth = QLineEdit()
        self.sixth = QLineEdit()
        self.seventh = QLineEdit()

        dlglayout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        formlayout = QFormLayout()
        formlayout.addRow("First Name:", self.first)
        formlayout.addRow("Second Name:", self.second)
        formlayout.addRow("Age:", self.third )
        formlayout.addRow("Sex:", self.fourth)
        formlayout.addRow("Marital Status:", self.fifth)
        formlayout.addRow("Education:", self.sixth)
        formlayout.addRow("Job:", self.seventh)
        dlglayout.addLayout(formlayout)
        btns = QDialogButtonBox()
        btns.setStandardButtons(QDialogButtonBox.Cancel | QDialogButtonBox.Save)
        dlglayout.addWidget(btns)
        btns.accepted.connect(self.accept)
        btns.rejected.connect(self.reject)

    def getInputs(self):
        return self.first.text(), self.second.text(), self.third.text(), \
        self.fourth.text(), self.fifth.text(), self.sixth.text(), self.seventh.text()

def writefile(data):
    wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename)
    ws = wb.worksheets[0]
    for c in range(2,100):
       if not ws.cell(2,c).value: break
    for r in range(len(data)):
       ws.cell(r+2,c).value = data[r]
    wb.save(filename)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    checkfile()
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    dialog = InputDialog()
    if dialog.exec():
        writefile(dialog.getInputs())
    exit(0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In openpyxml, you can set the cell borders using the `styles` object. For the headers, just create a string list and enumerate the values to set the cell values.

Add this code to `checkfile`:

```
def checkfile():
    ..........
        
    # write headers
    for c,v in enumerate(['Entry 1','Entry 2','Entry 3','Entry 4','Entry 5']): 
       ws.cell(1,c+2).value = v
       
    # define border 
    bdr = openpyxl.styles.borders.Side(style='thin')          
    thin_border = openpyxl.styles.borders.Border(left=bdr, right=bdr, top=bdr, bottom=bdr)
    # set cell borders 
    for c in  range(1, 7):
       for r in  range(1, 9):
          ws.cell(r,c).border = thin_border # set border

    wb.save(filename)
```